# How to free up memory used by iframes with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, iframe, setinterval

I currently create 20 hidden iframes and append them to a div container using plain javascript. Afterwards I parse each of the frames for a specific URL inside the frames loaded content and then remove them (.removeChild(...)).

I do this a few hundred times involving a setInterval with a 20 second delay. However after about 15 iterations Chrome uses about 5Gb of memory and counting until the site and chrome console chrashes.

How do I free this memory up without reloading the page or interrupting process?

Comment: You could try changing your design to re-use a pool of iframes instead of always creating new ones.  To start with try 2 x 20 and alternate between them.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: @DaveS Thank you for your suggestion. I redesigned the code for reusing the frames, but unfortunately the memory usage is still increasing.